# Using a plug-in timer to extend the lifespan of a laptop battery

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, laptop, battery-lifespan

My 3.5 year old laptop is suffering from a [swollen battery](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251466658) despite having completed only 100 cycles. It's been plugged in for at least 18 months, which [I read](https://www.wired.com/2013/09/laptop-battery/) likely contributed to its degradation.

I'm going to get it repaired but would like to take steps to prevent / delay this from happening again.

According to [this article](https://www.wired.com/2013/09/laptop-battery/) the 'optimum' charge for a Li-ion battery is 40%-80%, but more generally the advice seems to be to avoid leaving your laptop permanently plugged in.

One approach could to be plug the laptop into the mains through a [simple timer](https://xkcd.com/1495/), which could cut the power from 00:00 - 12:00, so that each day from when I switch the laptop on at 09:00 to 12:00 the battery would drain and then be recharged.

Aside from any performance issues of the laptop running on battery v.s. mains power, are there any drawbacks to this approach, and could I reasonably expect an improvement in the lifespan of the battery? Any advice on timing schedules - I could set the timer weekly rather than daily, for example - also appreciated.

Comment: I think swollen is bad news, swollen batteries can go bang, batteries shouldn't swell and if they are swollen they're already dead... I think?

Comment: Funnily enough the system reports that the condition of the swollen battery is 'normal' and it still seems to work reasonably well on battery power. But yes, I'll be getting it replaced asap. Looking to extend the life of the replacement battery

Comment: (though I notice that modern Macbooks are very thin, so perhaps it only takes a tiny amount of swelling to break the touchpad; I wouldn't imagine a *very slightly* swollen battery was in immediate danger of going bang)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually need to run the laptop not plugged in?  Is it an option to simply plug it in when you're using it or have the timer run for that period of time?

A 12 hour charge is likely to at least somewhat overcharge the battery, so you may wish to run it dead and see how long a full charge actually takes.  My laptop charges fully in about 1 hr and 45 minutes and it's nothing special.  I would think a modern laptop would only apply a periodic topping charge to a fully charged battery and that leaving it plugged in would produce few issues, but if it is damaging itself, yes, limiting overcharge time will increase battery life somewhat.  Outdoor block heater timers come to mind.  They're about $20 where I live and you can control the power cycle over the full day in 15 minute increments by flipping little tabs.

Comment: Useful input thanks and yes that's the kind of timer I was thinking about. It feels like a balancing act - a low number of charge cycles is bad for the battery (apparently), but so is a high number of charge cycles. I'm just looking to strike the middle ground with a solution I can implement and then forget about

Comment: If you're sure of the times of day you'll be using it and it's between 60 and 80% charge by the time you're done, you could protect it slightly more even by having it charge a bit before you use it instead of after you use it.  For long term storage just over half charge charge and just under 20 degrees C is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a good plan.  I expect that not charging over 80% will earn you most of the benefits and many short cycles vs few longer ones will make little difference, except that if you do need to run from battery then a shorter cycle is less likely to leave the battery in a relatively discharged state.

Comment: As an aside, a little gas goes a long way so a battery can be quite severely inflated without losing much if it’s capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Laptop batteries tend to have electronics under control of the laptop.  It will often be possible to find BIOS settings or fine-grained battery control applications that allow you to set a charge limit.  I use my laptop battery with a charge limit at 79% and it still holds up almost two hours (which is about 25% of the original capacity), and it's at cycle 2882 and has been first used 12 years ago.  I use it off the mains several times a week typically.  I do a full discharge and full recharge ("calibration") every few months.

If your laptop is not off the mains at all typically, you may want to go for a lower charge limit, such as 60%, and only do a full charge when you need to be off-grid for long enough to make it worthwhile.